# Fatal error of PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, element

I'm doing an admin panel and I'm doing a form for adding users. My code below:

```
        <form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Add user</legend>

<!-- Prepended text-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="newuser">Username</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
      <input id="newuser" name="newuser" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" type="text" required="">
    </div>
    <p class="help-block">Put the new users username here</p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Password input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="userpw">New user password</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input id="userpw" name="userpw" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control input-md" required="">
    <span class="help-block">Enter new user's password here!</span>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Select Basic -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="permissions">Choose permissions</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="permissions" name="permissions" class="form-control">
      <option value="1">System administrator</option>
      <option value="2">Editor</option>
      <option value="3">Developer</option>
      <option value="4">Normal user</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="btn_send">Send request to server</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button id="btn_send" name="btn_send" class="btn btn-primary">Send it!</button>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
<?php
$newuser = $_GET['newuser']; 
$userpw = $_GET['userpw'];
$permission = $_GET['permissions'];


if(isset($newuser and $userpw and $permission) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(username,userpw,permission)VALUES('$newuser', '$userpw','$permission')";

    mysql_query($sql);
}
else {
echo "error";}
```

And I Get:

Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in C:\xampp\htdocs\lumino\usermanagement.php on line 95

I couldn't fix it anyhow, playing with this for like 5 hours.
It's doing $_GET method, so I get the url like:

mysite.com/usermanagement.php?newuser=Berkay&userpw=18042003&permissions=3&btn_send=

Comment: `if(isset($newuser and $userpw and $permission)` guess what's missing?

Comment: @Fred -ii-  8-]  nothing else?

Comment: Thanks for answer, fixed.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions *Prolly*. But I didn't go any further in the code; call me lazy ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `isset`, you can't have multiple items inside it:

```
if(isset($newuser and $userpw and $permission) {
```

Needs to become:

```
if(isset($newuser) && isset($userpw) && isset($permission)) {
```

Or:

```
if(isset($newuser, $userpw, $permission)) {
```

Comment: Actually, you can have multiple values in an isset. `isset($a, $b, c)` http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: Thanks. Now how can I upload this to mysql table?

Comment: @BerkayGündüz - That's another issue. Mark the answer you think is best here and create another question where you explain the issues you're having with your database query.

Answer (score 1):

You just miss a `)` and a set of `,`:

```
if(isset($newuser, $userpw, $permission)) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(username,userpw,permission)VALUES('$newuser', '$userpw','$permission')";

    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Comment: He does have a valid point, though

Comment: Saw the missing `)` first (jumped to my eyes!). Just edited my answer.